# Java UDP sending and receiving thousands of data

Tags: java, udp

I have a database with different FPS games IP addresses and I need to query each server 5 in 5 minutes. With the query message response (received from the servers) I know if the server is online, how many players it has and some other data.

My problem is that not all server is responding to the query.

```
// Starting a listen server before sending any data to the servers.
new Thread(new ListenServer(socket)).start();

// Connecting and getting data from data base
MysqlData data = new MysqlData("localhost", "root", "abc123", "gm_database");
LinkedList<Map> query_data = data.mysql_fetch_assoc("SELECT * FROM gm_servers");

// Sending 16 bytes of data (Query message) for each server
for(Map<Integer, String> m : query_data){
   // m.get(0) is IP address, and m.get(1) is PORT
   send_packet = new DatagramPacket(buff, buff.length, InetAddress.getByName(m.get(0)), Integer.parseInt(m.get(1)));
   socket.send(send_packet);
}

System.out.println("Query header sent to " + query_data.size() + " servers. Total: " + query_data.size() * buff.length + " bytes of data.");
```

**Output:**

> Query header sent to 1200 servers. Total: 19200 bytes of data.

The ListenServer class (is listening for 60 seconds to get all responses from servers):

```
public class ListenServer implements Runnable{

   private DatagramSocket socket;

   public ListenServer(DatagramSocket socket){
      this.socket = socket;
   }

   @Override
   public void run(){
      long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

      int iServerResponse = 0;    

      // While is running for 60 seconds
      while(System.currentTimeMillis < startTime + 60000){
         byte[] buffer = new byte[256];

         DatagramPacket receive_packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
         socket.receive(receive_packet);

         iServerResponse++;

         // Reading bytes and other things...
      }

      System.out.println("Received response from " + iServerResponse + "servers.");
   }
}
```

**Output:**

> Received response from 651 servers.

As you can see, not all servers responded to the query. If I make a manual check I am getting a response.

What am I doing wrong? Am I need to start X threads for each server (1200+ Threads + ExecutorServer, etc)? I think it's the for-each cycle, I am sending too many data for too many addresses. Or it might be the listen server class.

Comment: How much data is being received by your machine, using something like netstat? You should be able to tell whether your application is actually receiving everything sent to your machine.

Comment: You are aware that UDP is unreliable?